# how to check if each input box exists by id and then check if that input box is not disabled and then loop in jquery?

Tags: jquery

How can I check 5 input boxes by ids and if they exist and not disabled then loop in jquery.

I want to include if the input box exists code as well for all input boxes to the following code:

```
$("#cf_2693809:not(:disabled), #cf_2693816:not(:disabled), #cf_2693823:not(:disabled), #cf_2693830:not(:disabled),#cf_2693837:not(:disabled)").each(function(){
....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```
var myIds = [
  "cf_2693809",
  "cf_2693816",
  "cf_2693823",
  "cf_2693830",
  "cf_2693837"
];
$("input:not(:disabled)").each(function(index, element) {
  if (myIds.indexOf($(element).attr("id")) >= 0) {
    // Do the thing
  }
});
```

This iterates each `input` element that is not `disabled` and if it's ID is in the Array, it will do something.

You may also try a better selector.

```
$("#cf_2693809, #cf_2693816, #cf_2693823, #cf_2693830, #cf_2693837").not(":disabled").each(function(){ ... });
```

**Example**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#cf_2693809, #cf_2693816, #cf_2693823, #cf_2693830, #cf_2693837").not(":disabled").each(function() {
    console.log("Found " + $(this).attr("id"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="cf_2693808" />
  <input type="text" id="cf_2693809" disabled />
  <input type="text" id="cf_2693816" />
  <input type="text" id="cf_2693823" />
  <input type="text" id="cf_2693830" />
  <input type="text" id="cf_2693837" />
  <input type="text" id="cf_2693840" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have 200 input boxes and with your approach I will get all of them if they are not disabled ($("input:not(:disabled)").each....) which is not very deficient.

Comment: @KarimAli then the second method might be advisable.